# Mysterious NullPointerException

Tags: java, exception, jpa, if-statement, nullpointerexception

I have the following code. It works fine. No exceptions etc. I am looping through a list of JPA Entity objects retrieved with a standard query (so there are not any `null` objects in the list).

```
for (PeriodicalTable periodical : resultsP){
        stringFor.add(periodical.getReference());
        site = em.find(SiteTable.class, periodical.getSiteID());
        if (site != null && site.getPostcode() != null && !site.getPostcode().equals("")){
            tempString = site.getPostcode().replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
            periodical.setPostcode(tempString.trim());                       
            }    
        }
```

Now, I have added in an `if` statement so that one line is only fired if the object in the list being looped has a `contractManagerID` of `0`. Marked below;

```
for (PeriodicalTable periodical : resultsP){
        if(periodical.getContractManagerID()==0) //<---- HERE!!!!
        {
            stringFor.add(periodical.getReference());
        }
        site = em.find(SiteTable.class, periodical.getSiteID());           
        if (site != null && site.getPostcode() != null && !site.getPostcode().equals("")){
            tempString = site.getPostcode().replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
            periodical.setPostcode(tempString.trim());                       
            }                
        }
```

After some debugging I have isolated the exception as coming from the if statement itself (marked "HERE"), but I don't understand how that can be. We know that there are no `null` objects in the list because otherwise it wouldn't work even without the if statement, but it works fine without it. I'm completely lost.

Comment: what is returned by `getContractManagerID()` ?

Comment: Are you sure `periodical.getContractManagerID()` is not itself null?

Comment: `getContractManagerID()` returns an Integer. There are no null values in the database, but even if there were the if statement would not be satiated and it would carry on surely?

Comment: @Rudi Kershaw; it may well be returning an Integer, but an Integer can be null. (cf. int). You need to check this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *only* possibility here is that `periodical.getContractManagerID()` is returning `null`.

Comparing `null == 0` will give you a `NullPointerException`.

Do this instead:

```
if (periodical.getContractManagerID() == null || 
    periodical.getContractManagerID() == 0)
```

Comment: Tried it and it works. Thank you. It does pose a question though. If the SQL table has 0 values against all the ContractManagerIDs, why would it return some 0s and some nulls, rather than all of one?

Comment: @Rudi Kershaw: perhaps that's the way the view on the database is representing null values.

Comment: Possibly, I suppose... but then there are other nulls visible in the database from Netbeans. Guess that bit will have to stay a mystery.

Answer (score 1):

There is a rather easy way to find that out:

- Set a breakpoint in the *HERE* line. When the Eclipse (I assume you use Eclipse) debugger pops up select the `periodical` variable and press `Ctrl + Shift + I` (this is called "Inspect"). If it is not null then evaluate `periodical.getContractManagerID()`. It should be `null`.

This means that you are not using a primitive to store that number. You should either use a primitive, add a sensible default or check for `null`.

If you have an `Integer` in your `PeriodicalTable` class that means it can be `null`.